# How should I initialize this multi-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, d

I have a giant 3-dimensional array that represents my world. It's too big to initialize statically:

```
alias Cell[128][128][128] World; // <-- The compiler points to this line

Error: index 128 overflow for static array
```

I tried using `World* world` but it still errors out with the overflow above. So what I have right now is this ugly mess:

```
alias Cell[][][] World;
// ...
private World world;
// ...
world.length = WORLD_XDIM;
for (uint x = 0; x < world.length; ++x)
{
    world[x].length = WORLD_YDIM;
    for (uint y = 0; y < world[x].length; ++y)
    {
        world[x][y].length = WORLD_ZDIM;
    }
}
```

That works, but it makes me cry a little on the inside. Is there a way to cast the result of calloc to a 3-dimensional array? I've done it with slicing regular arrays, but the 3-D thing is confounding me.

Comment: This is the 666th question tagged with [d]. Hmm.

Comment: And it is about my favorite D topic, definition/initialization of multi-dimensional arrays. I still dont get the semantics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to declare a jagged array (i.e. where each sub-array may have varying length), then you need to use a loop like you're doing, but that's unnecessary for uniform arrays. This is how you initialize a multi-dimensional array which isn't jagged:

```
auto arr = new Cell[][][](128, 128, 128);
```

When you put the numbers between the brackets, you're make it a dynamic array of static arrays. So,

```
auto arr = new Cell[128][128][128];
```

declares a dynamic array of a static arrays of length 128 of static arrays of length 128. I guess that it would be useful if you actually needed to do that (which I never have), but it definitely trips up newbies on a regular basis.

Personally, to avoid such issues completely, I just never put the numbers in between the brackets, even when declaring a single dimension array:

```
auto arr = new Cell[](128);
```

I find the fact that putting the number between the brackets on the first dimension is treated as a dynamic array while putting numbers in any further levels is treated as a static array to be a poor design choice, and I don't know why that's the way that it is, but that's the way that it is. I can understand wanting to be able to create dynamic arrays of static arrays, but it would have been far more consistent to either disallow `new Cell[128]` or to make it return a `Cell[128]*` rather than a `Cell[]` of length 128, but unfortunately, that's not how it works.